# Ubuntu 20.04 ImportError: No module named gtk.glade

Tags: 20.04, python-2.7, glade

i am trying to launch an old python2 script. On ubuntu 18.04 i installed python-glade2 and it worked, unfortunately ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have it in repositories. Is there a way to get this gtk.glade module? Maybe some other library that provides it?

@edit:
after following N0rbert's suggestions gtk/glade are installed but, unfortunately I also need python-gdal which I was trying to install in a similiar way and got error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies.  python-gdal : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3 but it is not installable                Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.2.2) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I assume that some packages from Ubuntu 20 that i need conflicts with the ones from ubuntu 18.

output of `apt-cache policy python-gdal libgdal20`:

`python-gdal:   Installed: (none)   Candidate: (none)   Version table: libgdal20:   Installed: (none)   Candidate: (none)   Version table:`

I am wondering if downloading .debs from ubuntu 18, then extracting only .py files and copying them into script directory is an only option here –

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get newest dependencies for current Ubuntu version.

Comment: it doesn't change apt-cache policy output. I think it's because python2 bindings are obsolete so the dependency libs were withdrawn

Comment: Do you have Gtk part solved? Can you `import gtk.glade` using `python2` ?

Comment: yes, I no longer get the `No module named gtk.glade` error.

Comment: So lets mark this problem solved (accept below answer). And then ask new question about Gdal.

Comment: problem from the topic is solved, for the new one I created [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262894/ubuntu-20-04-importerror-no-module-named-gdal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python-gtk2` with `python-glade2` may be installed manually using packages from 18.04 LTS by the commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thank you N0rbert, unfortunately I also need python-gdal which I was trying to install in a similiar way you suggested and got error:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python-gdal : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3 but it is not installable
               Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.2.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`
I assume that some packages from Ubuntu 20 that i need conflicts with the ones from ubuntu 18

Comment: Seems to be unrelated to Gtk issue. But anyway please add output of `apt-cache policy python-gdal libgdal20` to the question.

Comment: `python-gdal:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libgdal20:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
`
I am wondering if downloading .debs from ubuntu 18, then extracting only .py files and copying them into script directory is an only option here

Comment: Please add such information to question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1262685/edit). In comments they are hard to read.

Comment: I have editted the question describing steps done by me